# django rest framework email verification using generic view

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework

I am done with the registration as you can see. Now I want to send email verification so users can confirm. So once a user register, he/she gets a mail for confirmation.

how do I send email verification using "ListCreateAPIView"?

Do I need a third party package?

Can someone help me out? Thanks

Here is my view

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

My serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, style={'input_type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'})


    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        created_object = serializer.save()
        send_mail('Subject here','Here is the message.','from@example.com', 
            [created_object.email],  fail_silently=False,)
```

send email when object has been created

for create a link and verify follow this tutorial [doc](https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `django-djoser` [link](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).